# exporting label name from from web page using bsObj python

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i want to get the name of the url target from a webpage
this is what is have done so far :

```
check ='https://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword='+'N3580-5092'
r = requests.get(check)
html = requests.get(r.url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'xml')
storeName = bsObj.select_one('div.StoresLines div.BuyButtonsTxt')
```

the result is :

```
<div class="BuyButtonsTxt">
                ב-<a aria-label="לקנייה ב-פיסי אונליין Dell Inspiron 15 3580 
N3580-5092" href="/fs.aspx?pid=666473435&amp;sog=c-pclaptop" id="" 
target="_blank">פיסי אונליין</a>
</div>
```

i want only the value in the href : "פיסי אונליין"
how to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to change `bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'xml')` to `bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')`, as the 'xml' wouldn't find the tag for me

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import requests


check ='https://www.zap.co.il/search.aspx?keyword='+'N3580-5092'
r = requests.get(check)
html = requests.get(r.url)
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
storeName = bsObj.select_one('div.StoresLines div.BuyButtonsTxt')



text = storeName.find('a').text
```

**Output:**

```
'פיסי אונליין'
```